# Editing the cell of html table dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, dashboard

I have a JSON file and I have extracted data from it and displayed it into the html tables.

There are 60 tables, each has 3 cells and each cell has some value.

Now I want to display colours in the cells instead of numbers. So suppose if the number is 29673.4, then it should fill that particular cell with Green colour till 29% of that cell, and remaining 71% of the cell should be left with white colour, if the number is 90881.13333 then it should fill the particular cell with Green colour till 90% of that cell.

It is not allowing me to add screenshot as I am new to Stack Overflow and doesn't have 10 reputations.

I hope you understood my question.

Comment: 60 tables and 3 cells each? I think you're doing something backwards.

Comment: _"It is not allowing me to add screenshot as I am new to Stack Overflow and doesn't have 10 reputations."_ Post a link.

Comment: It is on my local computer so I can't post a link, I don't have access to the live site at the moment.

Comment: JSON file has 60 hosts and each has 3 GPUs, so 60 tables with 3 cells each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use two different colors in the same table cell, try assigning a [CSS gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 71%, #50aa50 72%); 
/* very little transition with 1% difference */
```

You can write a jQuery function that will color these cells automatically:

```
$('selector').each(function() {
    var v = 100 - ($(this).text() / 1000); // since we're coloring top-to-bottom
    $(this).css('background','linear-gradient(to bottom ,#ffffff '+v+'%, #50aa50 '+(v+1)+'%)');
});
```

([Current versions of jQuery should handle browser prefixing for this attribute as well](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/), when necessary.)

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NQCF8/

Comment: No I have a JSON file and it gives different values each time. 
I want the cell to be fill up 29% vertically if the value is 29000.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I am trying to use it in my code and see if it works.

Comment: This was really really helpful. This site really works, I was trying to figure out this for 1 week.
I want to vote up your answer but can't cuz they said I need 15 reputations.